# How to get the content of a <p> tag with no id or class, based on the previous element using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrapping a web page.

I am trying to get the content of a p tag that have no id or class but it is preceded by a span with a distinct class:

```
<p> uninteresting content here...</p>
<span class="description">DESCRIPTION:</span>
<p>Hi ! This is the content which I am interested in.</p>
<p> another uninteresting content to be discarded.</p>
```

So, How do I get that p content, based on the span class="description" that comes before it ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "description"}).find_next('p')
```